# Looking to take video of iphone app

Tags: iphone, video

Please let me know how i can create a video of iPhone app similar to the below video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6n582PIsMc&feature=player_embedded#at=18

Thank you,
Neal

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen capture utilities like [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm).  Also check out [SimFinger](http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/) to give that finger-press effect shown on the video.

As mentioned in the atebits.com blog, there is also [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) for screen capture